# Toggle classes with jQuery by clicking button and clicking other element than selected

Tags: jquery, html, toggleclass

I'd like to toggle the drawer with the 'drawer-toggle'-button, as shown in the snippet.

The only problem is that when the drawer is opened, I want to close it also with by clicking outside the .drawer-div.

Anyone could help me with this one? There must be a more efficient way.

*the .locked class is used for css purpose.*

```js
$(".drawer-toggle").click(function(e){
 $(".drawer").toggleClass('open');
 $(".main").toggleClass('locked');

 e.stopPropagation();
});

$(".main").click(function(){
 if ($(".drawer").hasClass('open')) {
  $(".drawer").toggleClass('open');
  $(".main").toggleClass('locked');
 }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.locked {  
 overflow: hidden !important;
}
.drawer {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: $white;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -200px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid $border-color;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.drawer.open {
  right: 0;
}
.drawer.open ~ .main {
  left: -200px;
}
.drawer.open ~ .main:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  z-index: 900;
}
.main {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.drawer-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drawer">
  <a class="drawer-toggle">toggle</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <a class="drawer-toggle">toggle</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Attach onclick to main container/body -> check if drawer opened -> close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a listener on the document and inside the handler check if the target is the drawer or a toggle button.

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  var $tgt = $(event.target)
  if (!$tgt.closest('.drawer').length && !$tgt.closest('.drawer-toggle').length && $('.drawer').hasClass('open')) {
    $(".drawer").removeClass('open');
    $(".main").removeClass('locked');
  }    
});
```